# Windows 7 and My Documents

Tags: windows-7

Coming from Windows XP to Windows 7 having ignored Vista. Active Directory running on Windows 2003. My Documents redirected by group policy to network share.

Main problem - my documents disappeared when logging onto Windows 7. The policy is setting as SET shows:

```
HOMEDRIVE=O:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\gandalf\users$\fred bloggs\my documents
```

I'm assuming this is something new in Windows 7 around libraries that I will read up on, honest... but anyone got a nice reference to an article on the changes for Windows XP/Windows 2003 familiar administrators?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Windows Server 2008 [Folder Redirection Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx) on TechNet, which covers some of the differences with folder redirection between XP and later versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that. A useful link. We've got our head around this now pretty much and it's one of those nice new features which makes Windows 7 a more attractive proposition.